# Amplifyjs GET request with body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, amplifyjs

I'd like to be able to use GET with message-body using AmplifyJS.

My question is specifically about how to achieve that with AmplifyJS.

Synthetic tests work fine (Fiddler being my test client). But when I do it through AmplifyJS, the "body" is added to the query string. (Edit: Is this a limitation of underlying jQuery "ajax" or that's AmplifyJS's choice)

```
amplify.request.define('trickyGet', 'ajax', {
                url: 'entity/{param}',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: '???'
            });
```

then

```
amplify.request({
                    resourceId: 'trickyGet',
                    data: { param: 'paramVal', data: JSON.stringify({'complex1': 'complex1Val'}) },
                    //data: { param: 'paramVal', data: {'complex1': 'complex1Val'}) },
                    success: callbacks.success,
                    error: callbacks.error
                });
```

I tried all kinds of combinations with how my complex data is represented and what `content-type` to use.

If I change `type` to POST (and of course change my API end point), everything works (`data` is in the message-body). But with get, `data` is appended to query string (by AplifyJS).

Comment: I'm afraid you don't quite understand HTTP. You don't construct a request body for HTTP GET. Request bodies are only for methods like POST, PUT, and PATCH. For methods like GET or DELETE, you can use the query string.

Comment: @CameronTinker, thank you for your help. I actually did some homework and as of now there seems to be a loophole (perhaps intentional) in the HTTP specification, that in fact allows GET requests to have a body. Very easy to google and find on stack - please check. Nonetheless - this is actually off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amplify.js uses jQuery's `ajax()` method, which in turn limits how `data` is sent during `get` requests.